# How to make zip etc. files appear as folders in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-provider

How can I make zip etc. files appear as folders in powershell? Does [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) have a concept of folder (item) providers akin to drive providers? Can this be done without implementing a drive provider?

Preliminary search turns up some useful [information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714636%28VS.85%29.aspx) but from the looks of it, it appears that I still need to implement the whole shebang.

Answer (score 3):

[John-Daniel Trask](http://blog.bluecog.co.nz/index.php) has a blog article about writing a [PowerShell Zip provider](http://blog.bluecog.co.nz/archives/2007/06/21/howto-write-a-powershell-drive-provider/) with source code.

Comment: From the blog "that will enable you to mount a zip file as a drive and then navigate through it." What I want is the ability to 'cd' into zip files present in various folders on the disk without mounting them as drives. You can do something similar with windows explorer (since WinXP). This will make the zip files appear as ordinary folders in the file system.

But thanks anyways for the link I found another link the comments section (http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/06/21/demo-sql-provider-code.aspx) which points to more relevant information.

Comment: That involves mounting the database as a drive.  ;)